# How to access column from another table in list_display?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I have these models:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'orders'

class OrderItems(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Orders, models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'order_items'
```

Now suppose I want `list_display` of the `orders` model to show the columns

`order_id, user_id, status, created_at, quantity`

I know I could do something like this:

```
class OrdersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ('id', 'user_id', 'status', 'created_at', 'get_quantity')

class Meta:
    model = Orders

def get_quantity(self, obj):
    result = XXX
    return result.get('quantity')

get_quantity.short_description = 'Quantity'

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

How can I access the information I need at `XXX`?

Comment: there are many order_items for one order, which quantity do you want to show?

Comment: For example where the order_id is 1.

Comment: I mean orders -> order_items is a 1-to-many relationship. There can be many order_items with order_id = 1. You want the sum of all quantities?

Comment: Also how are your models defined? Is order_id a ForeignKey to Order on OrderItem?

Comment: You should show the models rather than a picture of the db tables.

Comment: I added the definition of the models instead of the db tables.

Comment: I want to display all rows, so order_id = 1, quantity = 2, order_id = 1 quantity  = 10, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to follow the reverse foreign key set for Orders (which btw should be named in singular).
So something like this:

```
orderitems = obj.orderitems_set.all()
sum = 0
for orderitem in orderitems:
    sum = sum + orderitem.quantity
return sum
```

You can set `related_name` to rename the reverse set:

```
OrderItems(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Orders, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="order_items")
```

and call it like `order.order_items.all()`

To order in OrdersAdmin:

```
def get_queryset(self,request):
    qs = super(OrdersAdmin,self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.annotate(get_quantity=Sum('order_items__quantity'))

def get_quantity(self, obj):
    return obj.order_items.all.aggregate(Sum('quantity'))


get_quantity.admin_order_field = 'get_quantity'
```

Comment: If I put the five lines into a function in the class OrdersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) I get the error: 'Orders' object has no attribute 'orderitems_set'.

Comment: Can you try setting a `related_name` in your OrderItems model?  Then you can replace the first line by `orderitems = obj.related_name`. That should work.

Comment: Now I get the error: `'OrdersAdmin' object has no attribute 'related_name'`

Comment: Ah yeah, I meant it like this:  `OrderItems(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Orders, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="order_items")` and then use `orderitems = obj.order_items`

Comment: Looks better, yet it's not working. It tells me: `'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`. I might need the `all()` method if I want to iterate.

Comment: Yes that is true. You need to use `.all()`

Comment: Do you know what to do in order to make it possible to order the list_display by the column quantity?

Comment: `Orders.objects.annotate(quantity=Sum(F(order_items__quantity))).order_by('quantity')` could work. I've never worked with  annotate so I am not quite sure. If this works, I'd replace the loop in OrdersAdmin with a similar query, that should be more efficient.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a possible way to order by that field